# Filter or suppress runtime errors in metasploit scans

Tags: metasploit

Is there a command or options so results from metasploit scanning sessions don't print any runtime errors...

With so many errors mostly due to connections being reset by peers, it is quite difficult to keep track (from mobile phones)

[image: metasploit result]

Comment: Welcome to the community. So your goal is to suppress warnings and redirect them to `/dev/null`?

Comment: Just to tidy up the scan results...maybe some kind of method or command so the warnings doesn't showed up (since I already knew ,its either host are down or refusing connections) and for my need ,warnings as I have posted on screen shot doesn't really useful (for now) ...I want metasploit only print scanned host which are alive and responding

Comment: What command are you running? Have you looked at the "verbosity" levels?

Comment: Default run command, I've switched to my PC oddly runtime errors doesn't showed up which make me think that I might have no issue with metasploit..but my issues might be related to termux emulator (I run the scan via mobile phones)..but not sure